# I do not understand the error message

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I am using `ggplot2` to map shape files – I have been successful until now.
I ran the NOAA Hysplit model which creates a GIS shapefile.
I use `library(rgdal)` and `library(rgeos)` to read the shp.

However, I get the following message:

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class SpatialPointsDataFrame

Comment: `data.frame(SpatialPointsDataFrame)` may help

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22107702/2204410) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32235745/2204410) answer useful.